# Add content to media.phtml without modifying the code

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, custom, media

I have added custom code to media.phtml. media.phtml shows the product image.

The product images get cached and therefore my custom code is getting cached also and I do not want it to be.

What I want to know is, how do I add my code to the file without editing media.phtml?

I'm guessing XML but how?

Comment: What are you using to cache your content?

Comment: Lesti FPC extention

Comment: I've bumped into some issues with dynamic blocks using this module. If you have the xml block name, there should be an option in the backoffice to ignore certain blocks (i.e. make them not being cached)

Comment: I need to cache the image I cant do that but I am having trouble creating my own layout for the custom code